# Prophecies involving alcohol?

Tags: alcohol

When we read the *Life of Nostradamus*, we come across a rather strange little prophecy. Put in a short manner, it states  that **whoever drank from the skull of Nostradamus would inherit his incredible powers**.

> The introductory sequence had a subtitle 'France 1791' and showed a number of soldiers digging up a grave.
>
> The narrator spoke;
>
> > "There was a legend that whoever drank from the skull of Nostradamus would inherit his incredible powers. But for 200 years his grave had remained undisturbed because the legend also said that whoever did so, would immediately die. One night, at the height of the French Revolution, three drunken soldiers set out to test the legend.
> >
> > It was not the skeleton that suddenly sobered the soldiers, but the plaque around its neck, with the date: May 1791, which could only have been placed there at the time of burial in 1566, Nostradamus had predicted, 200 years before, the exact date when his body would be dug up."
>
> Anyway one of the soldiers poured some wine into the skull and took a swig. As he did so, a shot rang out, and he dropped, dead as well as drunk. - [NOSTRADAMUS: HIS IMAGINED LIFE](http://users.adam.com.au/bstett/PaNostradamus12.htm).

Thus my question: **Does anyone know of any prophecies (legends) of future events that involve the consumption of drinking alcohol in one form or another?**

Comment: 'Beer after wine and you'll feel fine; wine after beer and you'll feel queer.'

Comment: @DHydar Similarly: "Blanc sur rouge, rien ne bouge / Rouge sur blanc, tout fout le camp." (White after red, nothing stirs / Red after white, everything comes out.)

Comment: And in Germany I believe it runs : "Wein auf Bier / Das rat ich Dir. / Bier auf Wein / ist nur fuer Schwein" ( Wine on beer, that I advise. Beer on wine, only for pigs).

Comment: Interesting question... I wouldn't know about prophecies about alcohol. But, I imagine there many, many prophecies made after consuming alcohol  ;)